# Broken variable assignment with elif statements in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, package-management, variable

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(which yum) ]]; then
   OS="CentOS"
elif [[ $(which apt) ]]; then
   OS="Debian"
elif [[ $(which apk) ]]; then
   OS="Alpine"
elif [[ $(which zypper) ]]; then
   OS="OpenSuse"
elif [[ $(which pacman) ]]; then
   OS="Arch"
elif [[ $(which dnf) ]]; then
   OS="Fedora"
else
   IS_UNKNOWN=1
fi
echo "$IS_UNKNOWN"
suse="OpenSuse"
alpine2="Alpine"
cent="CentOS"
redhat="Fedora"
deb="Debian"
pacman="Arch"
if (( OS==suse ))
then 
    export package_manager="zypper install -y"
elif (( OS==alpine2 ))
then 
    export package_manager="apk --update add"
elif (( OS==cent ))
then 
    export package_manager="yum install -y"
elif (( OS==redhat ))
then 
    export package_manager="dnf install -y"
elif (( OS==pacman ))
then
    export package_manager="pacman -Sy"
elif (( OS==deb ))
then 
    export package_manager="apt install -y"
else
    printf "No package manager detected, aborting."
    exit 1
fi
echo "$package_manager"
```

Trying to detect the package manager of a linux user in bash , but it always seems to output zypper even when the package manager I'm using is not zypper and zypper is not installed.Anyone know what could be causing the problem?

Comment: The logic of your code is strange. You detect the an available package manager to figure out the OS, to figure out the package manager.  Couldn't you just skip the middle step there and just do `command -v zypper >/dev/null 2>&1 && pkg_mgr=zypper` etc.?

Comment: I didn't add the installation commands for the package manager before, now it should make more sense.

Comment: Note that most Linux distros these days have a file called [/etc/os-release](https://www.linux.org/docs/man5/os-release.html) which can be used to identify the distro.  e.g. `[ -f /etc/os-release ] && OS="$(awk -F= '{/^ID=/ {print $2}')"`.   Or, since the file contains shell-compatible variable assignments, you can just `source` the file and use the variables defined in it (`$ID` contains the distro short name that you're after).

Comment: It's cheating a bit, but if you assume `ansible` is available, installing a package, e.g. `zsh`, could be done on virtually any system with `ansible -bK -m ansible.builtin.package -a 'name=zsh state=present' localhost`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, `((...))` is strictly for arithmetic expressions. The words `OS` and `alpine` are taken as variable names, and as those variables don't contain numbers, they are given the value zero. `0==0` is true, so zypper.

What you want is the builtin `[[...]]` construct for string comparisons.

```bsh
if [[ "$OS" == "zypper" ]]
```

Take note that `[[` (as well as `[` and `test`) do different things based on *how many arguments they get*, which means it's really important to put spaces around the operator.